# is there a reliable way to know if a file is on the browser's cache with jQuery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know if a certain file (in this case, a video file) is already on the browser's cache. Is there any way of knowing this via javascript/jQuery? If not, where should I start looking to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Michal Zalewski, one of Google's security experts, has used browser's cache checks to determine whether some websites have been visited in the past, and the article referenced below claims this technique is reliable.

The article from ComputerWorld UK is titled [Google security expert highlights web browsing history vulnerabilities](http://www.computerworlduk.com/news/security/3323057/google-security-expert-highlights-web-browsing-history-vulnerabilities/).

The entry on Michal Zalewski's blog: [CSS :visited may be a bit overrated](http://lcamtuf.blogspot.com/2011/12/css-visited-may-be-bit-overrated.html).

Proof of concept: http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/cachetime/